# How do I return the response from a cy.intercept through a function

Tags: typescript, cypress

> cy.intercept(Cypress.env('apiUrl') + '/Account/profile',(request) =>{
>
> ```
>    request.continue((response) =>{ 
>       return response
>    }) 
>  });
> ```

Comment: Is there a need to return the value? Cypress' asynchronous approach makes this somewhat difficult. Could you not just use the response when given to you in the request?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to access the response of a request, you can use the `.its()` command.

```
cy.intercept(Cypress.env('apiUrl') + '/Account/profile')
  .its('response')
  // now you can use cypress commands on the response
```